# Undefined Function with Ng-Include in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm facing a problem with an undefined function in AngularJs and I didn't find any fitting solution on the internet:
I try to build a single page website. A few tabs are nested in the index.html with ng-include.

If i open the tab1.html allone the angular-functions work as expected. 
But if i open the index.html (with the embedded tab1.html) the function is undefined and the angular function dosn't work anaymore.

I would be very thankful if someone could help me!!!

-code below-

index.html

```
<!--Tab-Container-->
<div lang="en" ng-app="IndexPage" ng-cloak class="tabsdemoDynamicHeight" ng-cloak="">
<md-content>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="">

        <!-- Content TAB 1 -->
          <md-tab label="Tab1">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <div ng-include src="'views/tab1.html'"></div>
            </md-content>
          </md-tab>           

        <!-- Content TAB 2 --> 
        ...

      </md-tabs>      
</md-content>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">angular.module('IndexPage', ['ngMaterial']);</script>
```

index.js

```
angular.module('IndexPage',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']);
```

tab1.html

```
<body>
<div ng-app="tableapp" ng-controller="Ctrl" >
            <a href="#" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || "empty" }}</a>
        </div>
</body>
```

tab1.js

```
var tableapp = angular.module("tableapp", ["xeditable"]);

tableapp.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; // bootstrap3 theme. Can be also 'bs2', 'default'
});

tableapp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'awesome user'
  };  
});
```

Comment: You are not telling in index.js to include the tableapp module, try adding it as a dependency

Comment: Why are you defining `IndexPage` twice? (index.js and index.html)

Comment: remove the script tag from index.html  and replace it with script include tag.. to include index.js ...would be first thing to do ..

Comment: Also you are creating 2 seperate modules and app (viz. tableapp & IndexPage) .. no need to do it as well  .
Just include the tabs module in your main app..

Comment: Thanks for your fast help. I merged the index.js and tab1.js; I removed the redundant IndexPage definition but the error is still the same. How do I exactly add a dependency to the IndexPage module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define an `ng-app` inside an `ng-app`, and you definitely can't have multiple `<body>` tags on the same `html` page, and this is exacltly what happends when angular injects `tab1.html` template into your `index.html`.

If `tab1.html` is just a view inside your main `app`, it **can't** be in the form of

```
<body>
   <div ng-app="tableapp" ng-controller="Ctrl" >
            <a href="#" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || "empty" }}</a>
   </div>
</body>
```

But more like:

```
<div>
   <div ng-controller="Ctrl" >
            <a href="#" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || "empty" }}</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

And of course inject the `tableapp` module to your main `IndexPage` module.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me alot. Now my code is working!